# Ionic React - do you have to use Ionic UI components and routing?

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework

Looking at the ionic documentation they are pushing very heavily towards using Ionic components for UI and routing.

Is it possible to use your own components and frameworks instead of Ionic and simply use Ionic for its native feature support?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, You can just use Cordova. Because the Ionic is built on top of Cordova (It's just the wrapper). So you can reuse all Libs of Ionic with Cordova.

You can check these repositories:

https://github.com/unimonkiez/react-cordova-boilerplate

https://github.com/gitsad/react-cordova-boilerplate

Comment: Did not answer the question